# How can I create a page as a draft from my plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am developing a plugin for a WordPress install so lower users can submit a new page or page revision so an Editor can approve it.

I would like to do this by creating this post as a draft, then notifying an Editor via email...

Is this possible?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function wp_insert_post for this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

```
$my_post = array(
   'post_title' => $title,
   'post_content' => $content,
   'post_status' => 'draft',
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'post_author' => $author
);

wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

then you can use wp_mail(); to notify someone. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail